# How to get UILabel to display "..." at the end of a word rather than truncating it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uilabel, truncate

I would like to **display "..." at the end of the UILabel** when a word is too large **rather than simply truncating it** as shown below.

**For example in the image below the entry n. 2** (Minecraft) should display "..." at the end of the word Edition (like this: Edit...) and not truncate the word (like you can see below: Editio).

[image]

In the image you should be able to see the label options I set.

I tried to modify the **line break** value but I think is not the right approach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Set line break mode to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` (which you have set properly in NIB: Line Breaks = Truncate Tail).)

And in Auto layout, make sure your label never goes outside cell.

I expect your label is sizing itself automatically meaning if the text is too long, it just goes outside cell bounds. Add constraint "Trailing Space to superview" to label with value "is greater than N" (e.g. "> 15"). Using this, your label will never go outside bounds of superview and rather cut-off itself with "..." at the end as you want.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I need to change the autolayout value? Is it in the same tab that is displayed in the image above? (I can't see it)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a **width constraint** to your UILabel if you're using **Auto Layout**. If not, just try to decrease the UILabel width.

Answer (score 0):

Just decrease the label width that can display up to *Edit...*

set following values in Attribute Inspector

**Lines** set to *1*

**Line Breaks** set to *Truncate Trail*

It works in my case